# Probability that two numbers are close to each other

Tags: probability, integration, elementary-set-theory

I have A,B ~ unif(0,1). I want P(|A-B| < c).

Here's my attempt. I gather that there are other ways of doing this problem. I'm wondering specifically where I went wrong here using this approach:

$$
P(|A-B| < c) \\
= P(A-B < c | A > B)P(A>B) + P(B-A < c | B>A)P(B>A) \\
= P(A-B < c | A > B) \qquad \text{(symmetry)}\\
= P(A < B + c | A > B) \\
=  \int_0^1 P(A < B + c | A > B, B = b) f_B(b) db \qquad\text{(lotp)}\\
= \int_0^1 P(A < b + c | A > b, B = b) f_B(b) db \\
=  \int_0^1 P(A < b + c | B = b) f_B(b) / P(A > b | B = b) db \\
=  \int_0^1 P(A < b + c ) f_B(b) / P(A > b | B = b) db \\
=  \int_0^1 P(A < b + c ) f_B(b) / P(A > b ) db \\
=  \int_0^1 P(A < b + c ) f_B(b) / (1 - P(A < b )) db \\
=  \int_0^1 F_A(b+c) f_B(b) / (1 - P(A < b )) db \\
=  \int_0^1 F_A(b+c) f_B(b) / (1 - F_A(b)) db \\
=  \int_0^1 (b+c) f_B(b) / (1 - F_A(b)) db \\
=  \int_0^1 (b+c) f_B(b) / (1 - b) db \\
=  \int_0^1 (b+c) \cdot 1 / (1 - b) db \\
=  \int_0^1 (b+c)  / (1 - b) db \\
$$
which does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking. You want the area of a skinny hexagonal region near the $A=B$ diagonal of the unit square.  Sketch a picture, and the answer will pop out.  If you want to use integrals to do it, let the picture guide your choice of what to integrate over what ranges.  It's far less complicated than you have made it.